# How to apply StringEnumConverter in C# on single attribute of JSON object

Tags: c#, json, enums

I have a JSON object like

```
{
    "width": 200,
    "height": 150,
    "objectType": "container"
}
```

and in C# I have a class like

```
class MyObject {
    int width;
    int height;
    ObjectType objectType;
}
```

whereas `ObjectType` is an enum type:

```
enum ObjectType {
    container, banner
}
```

Now I want to deserialize the JSON object and transform the string `"container"` into the enum value `container`. For I am quiety new to C# I can't apply solutions to similar questions. I only found questions like "how to serialize a JSON array of enums?"

I think I must somehow apply StringEnumConverter but only to the attribute "objectType"?

I tried like

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new[] { new StringEnumConverter() }
};
MyObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObj>(strJson);
```

How do I correctly apply the StringEnumConverter to convert the JSON object to the given C# object?

Comment: Can you add also ObjectType ? You probably need `EnumMember` attribute

Comment: Just make your fields `public` and you'll be OK. Also, consider using properties instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decorate the Class property using `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`. This notifies JSON.net to only serialize this property to the enumeration name.
[source](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/serializing-enumerations-in-asp-net-web-api/)

Edit your model class:

```
public enum ObjectType
{
    container,
    banner
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int width;
    public int height;
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public ObjectType objectType;
}
```

and deserialize

```
 public void Test()
    {
        var json = "{\"width\": \"200\",\"height\": \"150\",\"objectType\": \"container\"}";
        MyObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you maybe explain (or at least tell me what to google) what this line you added in `MyObject` exactely does?

Answer (score 0):

Given your entity and enum:

```
public class MyObject {
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public ObjectType objectType;
}
public enum ObjectType {
    container, banner
}
```

Following deserialization will automatically return correct values:

```
string json=@"{
    ""width"": 200,
    ""height"": 150,
    ""objectType"": ""container""
}";

JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
s.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
MyObject output = s.Deserialize<MyObject>(json);
```